# record_defaults of tf.decode_csv in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I used tf.decode_csv in tensorflow as decoder to parse training examples in a tab-delimited file into cnn models. For every training example, the features are 2 dimensions (100 columns, 2000 rows). After reading the document in tensorflow official site, I still have two questions.

1. how to create record_defaults? The following is my code to do that, but I
   am not sure if it is right.

code

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([file], num_epochs)

key, value = tf.TextLineReader().read(filename_queue)

record_defaults = [[1.0 for col in range(0, 100)] for row in range(0, 2000)]

content = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults = record_defaults, field_delim = '\t')

features = tf.pack(content[0:1999])
```

2. I am doing binary (0, 1) classification. Where do I put the labels for training examples? in the 2001th row? (For every training example, the first 2000 rows for features, and the 2001th row for label)

Thanks for your time!